# Aspose VB.NET Bar Chart Value

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint, aspose

I am setting up a bar chart that will end up exported into a PowerPoint slide.  I've got it exporting perfectly fine but it has been requested that at the top of each bar the value of that bar is placed right above it.  I've looked high and low and unfortunately haven't been able to find out how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work as Social Media Developer at Aspose. Check the following sample code to set the custom labels as Values and setting the position of the label.

```
'Instantiate Presentation class that represents PPTX file
Dim pres As New Presentation()

'Access first slide
Dim sld As ISlide = pres.Slides(0)

' Add chart with default data
Dim chart As IChart = sld.Shapes.AddChart(ChartType.ClusteredBar, 0, 0, 500, 500)

'Setting chart Title
'chart.ChartTitle.TextFrameForOverriding.Text = "Sample Title";
chart.ChartTitle.AddTextFrameForOverriding("Sample Title")
chart.ChartTitle.TextFrameForOverriding.TextFrameFormat.CenterText = NullableBool.True
chart.ChartTitle.Height = 20
chart.HasTitle = True

'Set first series to Show Values
chart.ChartData.Series(0).Labels.DefaultDataLabelFormat.ShowValue = True

'Setting the index of chart data sheet
Dim defaultWorksheetIndex As Integer = 0

'Getting the chart data worksheet
Dim fact As IChartDataWorkbook = chart.ChartData.ChartDataWorkbook

'Delete default generated series and categories
chart.ChartData.Series.Clear()
chart.ChartData.Categories.Clear()
Dim s As Integer = chart.ChartData.Series.Count
s = chart.ChartData.Categories.Count

'Adding new series
chart.ChartData.Series.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 1, "Series 1"), chart.Type)
chart.ChartData.Series.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 2, "Series 2"), chart.Type)

'Adding new categories
chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 0, "Caetegoty 1"))
chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 0, "Caetegoty 2"))
chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 0, "Caetegoty 3"))

'Take first chart series
Dim series As IChartSeries = chart.ChartData.Series(0)

'Now populating series data

series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 1, 20))
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 1, 50))
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 1, 30))

'Setting fill color for series
series.Format.Fill.FillType = FillType.Solid
series.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red

'Set Data Labels for first series
For Each point As IChartDataPoint In series.DataPoints
    Dim lbl As IDataLabel = point.Label
    lbl.DataLabelFormat.ShowValue = True
    lbl.DataLabelFormat.Position = LegendDataLabelPosition.OutsideEnd
Next point

'Take second chart series
series = chart.ChartData.Series(1)

'Now populating series data
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 2, 30))
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 2, 10))
series.DataPoints.AddDataPointForBarSeries(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 2, 60))

'Setting fill color for series
series.Format.Fill.FillType = FillType.Solid
series.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green

'Set Data Labels for first series
For Each point As IChartDataPoint In series.DataPoints
    Dim lbl As IDataLabel = point.Label
    lbl.DataLabelFormat.ShowValue = True
    lbl.DataLabelFormat.Position = LegendDataLabelPosition.OutsideEnd
Next point

'Save presentation with chart
pres.Save("c:\data\AsposeChart.pptx", Aspose.Slides.Export.SaveFormat.Pptx)
```

Following is the sample from the above code to give an idea how to setup the labels.

```
   'Set Data Labels for first series
    For Each point As IChartDataPoint In series.DataPoints
        Dim lbl As IDataLabel = point.Label
        lbl.DataLabelFormat.ShowValue = True
        lbl.DataLabelFormat.Position = LegendDataLabelPosition.OutsideEnd
    Next point
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's helped tremendously.  I have a follow up question though.  I've gone through the Aspose website and couldn't find specific information on cycling through a dataset and creating a table from it based on column names and specific rows.  Do you happen to have sample code like the one you posted in the answer above?

Comment: Could you elaborate your requirement abit with an example. I will be happy to assit you.